# Copy Folder (contents included) and Paste in Archive Folder with Date

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I'm new to PowerShell and have a task to copy a folder and its contents to an archive folder. The copied folder must be renamed with the date as well.

I've been working on some test folders but am having trouble figuring out how to copy the folder + its contents, let alone rename the copied folder.

I'm able to move a folder with

```
Copy-Item -Path C:\Test -Destination C:\Archive
```

But the contents don't come with. I'm also not sure how to apply to best apply

```
$Date = (Get-Date -UFormat "%m%d%Y")
(Get-Date -UFormat "%m%d%Y")
```

In order to rename the copied folder with the date.

Comment: `Copy-Item -Path 'C:\Test' -Destination "C:\Archive\$Date" -Recurse`

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create the backup folder first with the date in the name, then copy all the contents from the source, recursively.

```
$source = 'C:\Temp'
$backupDestination = 'C:\Backups'

# Will Create: 2019-02-20T15.43.05    
$backupDate = (get-date -Format s) -replace ':', '.'

# sourceName will be set to "Temp"
$sourceName = (Get-Item $source).BaseName

# Combine the destination with the source name and the backup date
# to create C:\Backup\Temp-2019-02-20T15.43.05
$backupDirectory = Join-Path $backupDestination "$sourceName-$backupDate"

# Create the backup destination directory
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $backupDirectory

# Copy everything recursively
Copy-Item $source\** $backupDirectory\ -Recurse
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help! I definitely have a lot to learn still!

Comment: You are welcome! Powershell is awesome and has some really nice self documenting features (for future references), just type Get-Command to list all available commands, then get help with: help Copy-Item -examples|-full|-detailed.